# How to populate google charts using ASP.NET Dataset/Datatable?

Tags: asp.net

How to populate google charts using ASP.NET Dataset/Datatable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert the Datable into JSON and then parse it in the javascript using jquery. Here goes the example :

http://www.techipost.com/2011/02/24/google-charts-in-asp-net-web-application/

Answer (score 0):

For converting your `DataTable` to JSON you might find the [bortosky-google-visualization](http://code.google.com/p/bortosky-google-visualization/) library useful.